# Python3 inconsistent output inside open function and for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code. Somehow the output is not consistent. There is a new line for the first 2 lines in `ip.txt` while the third is working as expected.

**code.py**

```
import subprocess

with open('ip.txt') as f:
    for IPAddr in f:
        ping = subprocess.Popen(['ping','-c','1',IPAddr],stdout=f).wait()
        if ping == 0:
            print(f'{IPAddr} is up')
        else:
            print(f'{IPAddr} is down')
```

**ip.txt**

```
127.0.0.1
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

**Output**

```
user@linux:~$ python 01.py 
127.0.0.1
 is up
10.0.0.1
 is down
127.0.0.1 is up
user@linux:~$
```

**Desired Output**

```
user@linux:~$ python code.py 
127.0.0.1 is up
10.0.0.1 is down
127.0.0.1 is up
user@linux:~$
```

What's wrong with this code and how to fix it?

**Update**

The following solutions work! Many thanks

```
IPAddr = IPAddr.replace('\n','')
IPAddr = IPAddr.rstrip("\n")
IPAddr = IPAddr.strip()
```

Comment: when you read lines from file then you get it with `\n'` at the end so you have to `strip()` line to remove it

Comment: Thanks @furas, I didn't know that. `.strip()` works.

Comment: you can also use `.rstrip()` as mentioned in other comment. Or you can use `f.read().splitlines()` and then you get lines without `'\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including the newline characters from your file in your print.

Remove the `\n` like this:

```
import subprocess

with open('ip.txt') as f:
    for IPAddr in f:

        IPAddr = IPAddr.replace('\n', '')  # Remove the newline

        ping = subprocess.Popen(['ping','-c','1',IPAddr],stdout=f).wait()
        if ping == 0:
            print(f'{IPAddr} is up')
        else:
            print(f'{IPAddr} is down')
```

Or if you want to do it more broadly, you can remove all whitespace by using:

```
IPAddr = IPAddr.strip()
```

Or if you want to be super duper efficient, just strip the `\n` from the right:

```
IPAddr = IPAddr.rstrip("\n")
```

Comment: Hint: since iterating over a file uses the newline marker to split the file's content, the newline marker can only be at the end of the string here, so `.rstrip("\n")` will be more efficient (by not uselessly scanning the entire string). Ok, micro-optimization, but it also makes the intent clearer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over a file line by line, each line ends with the newline marker (`"\n"`), so what you pass to `print()` is actually `"127.0.0.1\n is up"`, not `"127.0.0.1 is up"`.

The solution is quite simple: remove the newline:

```
for IPAddr in f:
   IPAddr = IPAddr.rstrip("\n")
   # etc
```

Note that since external inputs (files, user inputs etc) are totally unreliable, you would be better stripping all whitespaces from the line, check it's not empty (it's common to  have empty lines in text files, specially at the end) and then skip that line (with a `continue` statement), and if not empty you probably want to validate the value is a valid IP address (and if not skip it too)...

Comment: Just to be safe, in this case OP should better use `.strip()` to ensure no white space of any kind is still there. (E.g. `\r` might be an issue for other OS.)

Comment: @BramVanroy yeps, I accidentally hit the submit button before I finished typing my answer ;-) - this (and other possible issues) are mentionned in the (now) full answer. This being said Python3 `open()` defaults to using "universal newline" so this shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: @Sabrina yes, both works, but they don't do exactly the same thing (cf the doc for more on those methods). For your current use case `.strip()` is better since you expect one IP per line but for some other cases you'd possibly want to only remove the trailing newline marker.